# Api credentials for AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I created a new AWS account for AWS ECS. IN Jenkins I installed AWS ECS plugin and now I want to build and push images into registry.

But I need to create API key and secret in AWS in order to Jenkins to communicate with AWS ECR.

How I have to create in AWS these credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an IAM user by following this documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html

Comment: ok I created IAM user. But from my main user I created ECR registry. When I logged in from the IAM user I can't see the other registry in the list. Any idea how to make the registry visible for both accounts?